# Keepsorted function

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to solve a problem on a function called "keepsorted";

This function has to keep a sub-list of growing number form a list called l1.

For example if I have `let l1 = [1; 2; 0; 1; 2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]` the return is a list with the numbers `[1; 2; 2; 4; 5; 6]`

I tried many solution but I don't understand.

My last solution is:

```
let rec keepsorted l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> [] 
  | a1::a2::r when a1 >= a2 -> a1::keepsorted r 
  | a::r -> a::keepsorted r;;
```

and the result is:

```
- : int list = [1; 2; 1; 2; 4; 5; 2; 6]
```

Comment: What do you not understand? What's your reasoning for the current implementation, and where do you think it breaks down?

Comment: `a1::a2::r when a1 >= a2 -> a1::keepsorted r` should be `a1::a2::r when a1 >= a2 -> keepsorted (a1::r)`

Comment: beacuse when i do a1::keepsorted r i save the valor a1 with the problem that you solve. But when i do keepsorted(a1::r) i dont see where i save the valeur a1 ( like 2>1? Yes so i redo keepsorted of 2 and the rest of my list, and i dont save the valeur 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues with this line:

```ml
a1::a2::r when a1 >= a2 -> a1::keepsorted r
```

The first issue is that you're removing `a1` from the recursive call, so the next number will always be accepted without begin compared to `a1`.

For instance, consider the list `10 :: 9 :: 8 :: r`:

```ml
keepsorted (10::9::8::r)
10 :: keepsorted (8::r)
10 :: 8 :: ...
```

10 was never compared to 8.

You can fix that issue easily by doing instead:

```ml
a1::a2::r when a1 >= a2 -> keepsorted (a1::r)
```

Now `a1` can be compared with the next element of `r`

The second issue is that you're discarding `a2` when `a1 >= a2`, but your example says that you only want to discard `a2` when `a1 > a2`. In case of equality, keep both.

Final function:

```ml
let rec keepsorted l = 
  match l with
  |[] -> [] 
  |a1::a2::r when a1 > a2 -> keepsorted (a1::r) 
  |a::r -> a::keepsorted r;;
```

Comment: Thanks, i have just a problem to understad how it works the "keepsorted (a1::r)". I see the problem but i don't see where i save the value a1 in the list, i'm new with ocaml hihi

Comment: @SeveN I strongly suggest "unrolling by hand" on an example. Pick up a pen and paper. Take the expression `keepsorted (1::2::0::1::2::4::3::5::3::2::6::[])` and rewrite it by hand using the pattern matching rules: `keepsorted (1::2::0::1::2::4::3::5::3::2::6::[])` --> `1 :: keepsorted (2::0::1::2::4::3::5::3::2::6::[])` --> `1 :: keepsorted (2::1::2::4::3::5::3::2::6::[])` --> ... --> `1::2::2::4::5::6::keepsorted []` --> `1::2::2::4::5::6::[]`.

Comment: @SeveN You start with `keepsorted l` and you match `l` to `a1::a2::r`, so that means what you really had was `keepsorted (a1::a2::r)`; and you replace that with `keepsorted (a1::r)` so you can see that what happens is `a2` was dropped, while `a1` is not dropped. On the next iteration, `a1` will be compared with the next element in the list. However if instead you had replaced `keepsorted (a1::a2::r)` with `a1 :: keepsorted r`, then `a1` is going to be in the final result, but the next iteration is going to compare the next two elements together, instead of comparing the next element with `a1`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Stef's answer, which is correct, you need to keep track of the last value you added to the output as you iterate, and the current element. This isn't very efficient if we build up the list in the right order, but it *is* if we build it up in reverse order using a left fold. At the end we then just need to reverse that list.

```
let keepsorted lst =
  let f i x = 
    match i with
    | [] -> x::i 
    | y::_ when x >= y -> x::i 
    | _ -> i
  in
  lst
  |> List.fold_left f [] 
  |> List.rev
```

If we consider how this works for your test case:

```
keepsorted [1; 2; 0; 1; 2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [] [1; 2; 0; 1; 2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [1] [2; 0; 1; 2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [2; 1] [0; 1; 2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [2; 1] [1; 2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [2; 1] [2; 4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [2; 2; 1] [4; 3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [4; 2; 2; 1] [3; 5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [4; 2; 2; 1] [5; 3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [5; 4; 2; 2; 1] [3; 2; 6]
List.fold_left f [5; 4; 2; 2; 1] [2; 6]
List.fold_left f [5; 4; 2; 2; 1] [6]
List.fold_left f [6; 5; 4; 2; 2; 1] []
List.rev [6; 5; 4; 2; 2; 1]
[1; 2; 2; 4; 5; 6]
```

Side benefit: this is naturally tail-recursive, though that won't matter for trivial datasets.